# openjdk setting keepalive time in windows 10

Tags: java, windows, timeout, keep-alive

I'm working in java (openjdk14) on a project that sends files to a webservice. The server takes its time to process this files so I need to set the TCP keepalive time in order to not lose the connection. Is there any way to set the TCP keepalive time in windows?

I'm using openjdk14 and Windows 10 Pro

I will appreciate any help

I found a way in linux using ExtendedSocketOptions but in Windows it seems that it's not supported:

```
`Socket sock = sf.createSocket(context);

sock.setOption(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 60);
sock.setOption(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPCOUNT, 75);
sock.setOption(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPINTERVAL, 3); `
```